# Vue js - pass data within two components in the same level

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have data that I need to pass from one `component1` to another `component2`.

I don't use *vuex* or *router*.

Components tree:

```
-Parent
--Component1
--Component2
```

From first `component1` I make ajax request, retrieving info and pushing to data.

```
board: [1,2,3,4,5]
```

And I need access that retrieved data in `component2`

Can I do It without *vuex* or *router* ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Are parent child components? Or components of brother-in-law?

Comment: Component1 and Component2 is childs of Parent component

Comment: solved the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could emit an event to parent from `component1` having as parameters the updated `board` and in the parent one receive that and pass it through `props` to `component2`

In `component1` :

```
this.$emit("sendToComp2",this.board);
```

in the `parent` component :

```
  <template>
  <component1  @sendToComp2="sendTo2"/>
  ...
  <component2 :boards="boards" />
  ....
  </template>


  data:{
    boards:[]
    },
  methods:{
       sendTo2(boards){
        this.boards=boards
          }
      }
```

`component2` should have property called `boards`

```
  props:["boards"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that you have a Parent component which has at least two child components. The child components can trigger an event in the parent component and from Parent to child. So, if Component1 needs to send a message to Component2, it can trigger an event to Parent and then Parent trigger an event for Component2. Example:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Car',
  methods: {
    handleClick: function() {
      this.$emit('clickedSomething')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Car v-on:clickedSomething="handleClickInParent" />
    <!-- or -->
    <Car @clickedSomething="handleClickInParent" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  methods: {
    handleClickInParent: function() {
      //...
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Source: https://flaviocopes.com/vue-components-communication/

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the "common ancestor pattern".

Consider the following `Parent` component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <child-one :onData="onDataFromChildOne"></child-one>
    <child-two :newData="dataToChildTwo"></child-two>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "Parent",
    data() {
      return {
        dataToChildTwo: null
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onDataFromChildOne(data) {
        this.dataToChildTwo = data;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The `ChildOne` component will receive a function as a `prop` named `onData` that should be called when the ajax call is finished. Then:

```
<script>
  import axios from 'axios';

  export default {
    name: "ChildOne",
    props: ['onData'],
    beforeMount() {
      axios
        .get('/data')
        .then(res => {
          this.onData(res.data);
        });
    }
  }
</script>
```

When `onData` gets executed, `dataToChildTwo` will be updated and `ChildTwo` will receive the new data.