# Vue communcation between child to parent to another child

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got a `<payment-child-component>` which handles all the subscriptions and payments, i also have

another `<check-active-child-component>`

I want these two components to communicate. persay in the `<payment-component>` a user cancel's his subscription i want to fire a method i have in `<check-active-component>` which called `checkActive()`

So from `payment-component` emits to `parent-component` when the subscription cancel method is triggered and then fires the `checkActive()` method inside `check-active-component`

So if my logic is good, the exact question is: **how do i fire a method from parent to child component?**

Comment: Would you consider using the store (Vuex) for this?

Comment: please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53254935/8172857)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a method of a child component from its parent, you can use `ref`. Here is an example:

Child Component:

```
export default {
  name: "ChildComponent",
  methods: {
    childMethod(){
      console.log("hello from child");
    }
  }
};
```

Parent Component:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ChildComponent ref="myChild"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from "./components/ChildComponent";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    ChildComponent
  },
  mounted(){
    this.$refs.myChild.childMethod()
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is what I am using on my app.

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>
    <a @click="run">Click me to execute method from child</a>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name:"parent",
        methods: {
            run() {
              this.$root.$refs.child.methodtoexecute();
            }
         }
     }
</script>
```

**Child.vue**

```
<script>
   export default {
     name:"child",
     created() {
        this.$root.$refs.child = this;
     },
     methods: {
        methodtoexecute() {
          alert("hello from child");
        }
     }
   }
</script>
```